# How to Create/Load and Download a File throught Google Drive API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a file in Google Drive through Google Drive API.I managed to create the file, but I couldn't load the attachment in the file.

To create the file I Have used this Endpoint

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media
```

with the `Content-type : application/pdf header`

And this body (but it was not taken from google => the file generated don't have a title and the description):

```
{
"title": "prova.pdf",
"mimeType": "application/pdf",
"description": "Stuff about the file"
}
```

Then I tried to load the attachment in this file (using base64 encoding)through a call to this endpoint

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/{FILEID}
```

with thesetwo headers:

- `Content-type: application/pdf`
- `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`

And in the body (raw - text) I put the base64 encoded file.

The call doesn't return an error but now if I open the file on the Google Drive I see the base64 string in place of the pdf file.

Then I tried downloading the file. I tried with

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}
```

but this call retrieves a 'webContentLink' so I have to open this link in the Browser, authenticate with my account and then the download starts.

It's possible to retrieve the document as a base64 string directly from the call?

Comment: You currently ask two questions, probably better to post them as separate ones to get more focus and better replies. I did some edits to the language and formatting to help with folks reading this to help.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the download part? Are you trying to download without authorizing or is the issue that you want the file specifically in base64 format?

Comment: I want to upload and then download the file in base64 format